# Scala 2.13 error: overloaded method w with alternatives

Tags: scala, methods, migration

I migrate some code to scala 2.13 from 2.12 and I have the following code

```
def w(value : java.util.Map[String, java.util.List[String]]) : ParamPair[Map[String, (String, String)]] = {
    val scalaMap = value.asScala.toMap

    val newMap = scalaMap.mapValues[(String, String)]( (l : java.util.List[String]) => {
      if(l.size() != 2)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("A tuple map should contain exactly 2 elements ")
      val lScala = l.asScala.toArray
      (lScala(0), lScala(1))
    })

    w(newMap)
  }
```

that at the last line i get the error

```
 error: overloaded method w with alternatives:
[ERROR]   (value: java.util.Map[String,java.util.List[String]])org.apache.spark.ml.param.ParamPair[Map[String,(String, String)]] <and>
[ERROR]   (value: Map[String,(String, String)])org.apache.spark.ml.param.ParamPair[Map[String,(String, String)]]
[ERROR]  cannot be applied to (scala.collection.MapView[String,(String, String)])
[ERROR]     w(newMap)
[ERROR]     ^
```

can you explain what is the problem?

Comment: Isn't your method infinite recursive or I'm missing something..

Comment: Anyway, add types to your variables and it should be more clear what's going on. Hint: `mapValues` has changed between 2.12 and 2.13.

Answer (score 3):

There were some breaking changes for collections introduced in scala 2.13. Here you have the [migration guide for collections in scala 2.13](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/collections-migration-213.html#what-are-the-breaking-changes)

> ##### What are the breaking changes?
>
> - `collection.JavaConversions`. Use `scala.jdk.CollectionConverters` instead. Previous advice was to use `collection.JavaConverters` which is now deprecated
>
> | Description | Old Code | New Code | Automatic Migration Rule |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | mapValues and filterKeys now return a MapView instead of a Map | `kvs.mapValues(f)` | `kvs.mapValues(f).toMap` | RoughlyMapValues |

First you have to replace the import for the collection converters. Then, you have the following old code

```scala
   val newMap = scalaMap.mapValues[(String, String)]( (l : java.util.List[String]) => {
      if(l.size() != 2)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("A tuple map should contain exactly 2 elements ")
      val lScala = l.asScala.toArray
      (lScala(0), lScala(1))
    })
```

In scala 2.12, [Map.mapValues](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.18/scala/collection/Map.html#mapValues%5BW%5D(f:V=%3EW):scala.collection.Map%5BK,W%5D) returns a `Map`.

> ```scala
> def mapValues[W](f: (V) ⇒ W): Map[K, W]
> ```
>
> Transforms this map by applying a function to every retrieved value.

Scala 2.13 [Map.mapValues](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.11/scala/collection/Map.html#mapValues%5BW%5D(f:V=%3EW):scala.collection.MapView%5BK,W%5D) returns a `MapView`.

> ```scala
> def mapValues[W](f: (V) => W): MapView[K, W]
> ```
>
> Transforms this map by applying a function to every retrieved value.
> **Deprecated** (*Since version 2.13.0*) Use `.view.mapValues(f)`. A future version will include a strict version of this method (for now, `.view.mapValues(f).toMap`).

This means that the signature of the method have been changed and also the method is deprecated. As it is detailed in the migration guide and in the scaladoc of the method, you should use `map.view.mapValues(transformation).toMap`. In your code should be something like

```scala
   val newMap = scalaMap.view.mapValues[(String, String)]( (l : java.util.List[String]) => {
      if(l.size() != 2)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("A tuple map should contain exactly 2 elements ")
      val lScala = l.asScala.toArray
      (lScala(0), lScala(1))
    }).toMap
```

The last line `(lScala(0), lScala(1))` is a `Tuple2[String,String]`, making `newMap` of type `Map[String, (String, String)]`. In the next line you are calling `w` function which expects a `java.util.Map[String, java.util.List[String]]`. Doing `newMap.asJava` will return a `util.Map[String, (String, String)]`.

---

You have the [Views](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections-2.13/views.html) for further reading

> Collections have quite a few methods that construct new collections. Examples are `map`, `filter` or `++`. We call such methods transformers because they take at least one collection as their receiver object and produce another collection as their result.
>
> There are two principal ways to implement transformers. One is `strict`, that is a new collection with all its elements is constructed as a result of the transformer. The other is `non-strict` or `lazy`, that is one constructs only a proxy for the result collection, and its elements get constructed only as one demands them.