# Scala 2.13 No implicit view available from java.util.Map[String,Double] => scala.collection.IterableOnce[B]

Tags: scala, scala-2.13

I migrate some scala code from 2.12 to 2.13 and I have the following code

```scala
def getMetrics(): java.util.Map[String, Double] ={
    transformers.map{
      case transformer => transformer match{
        case t: EvaluationTransformFunction => t.getMetric.asJava
      }
    }.flatten.toMap.asJava
  }
```

that produces the error

```
error: No implicit view available from java.util.Map[String,Double] => scala.collection.IterableOnce[B].
[ERROR]     }.flatten.toMap.asJava
[ERROR]       ^
```

can you explain what is the error about?

Answer (score 2):

We're missing a bit more info about the exact types you are manipulating but the idea is that:

- the type of `transformers.map(...)` is a `Iterable[SomeJavaCollectionType]`
- `flatten` works only if `SomeJavaCollectionType` can be "transformers/"viewed" as a `Iterable[SomeOtherType]` so that `Iterable[SomeJavaCollectionType]` can be viewed as `Iterable[Iterable[SomeOtherType]]` and thus flattened
- there's no such "implicit view" available for your actual `SomeJavaCollectionType` which seems to be `JavaMap[String, Double]` if I read it correctly

I'm slightly surprised it was working in Scala 2.12. Maybe there's an `import` that would make it work in Scala 2.13 as well (i.e. bring the "implicit view" in scope).

Anyway, I would just get rid of the inner `asJava` and only convert to Java collection at the end of your method:

```scala
def getMetrics(): java.util.Map[String, Double] ={
    transformers.map{
      case transformer => transformer match{
        case t: EvaluationTransformFunction => t.getMetric
      }
    }.flatten.toMap.asJava
  }
```

Comment: Oh. This question is similar to [Scala 2.13 error: overloaded method w with alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76872361/scala-2-13-error-overloaded-method-w-with-alternatives). My answer about [how to migrate collections to scala 2.13](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76872849/7214091), might help to complement this answer.